# python adding to dictionary from external file

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I have an external file that I need to have into a dictionary. Each article begins with `<NEW DOCUMENT>`, and I am unaware of how I can pull all the information from the file, starting on the line below `<newdoc>` and ending before reaching the other `<newdoc>`. Here is what I have so far.

```
for line in file2:
    line = line.strip()
    line_list = line.split()
    if "NEW DOCUMENT" in line:
        doc_num+=1
        new_dict[doc_num] = line
        print(new_dict)
```

The file looks like this.

```
<NEW DOCUMENT>
Look on the bright 
side of Life.
<NEW DOCUMENT>
look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modification to your solution:

```
docs = []
document = []
for line in file2:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "<NEW DOCUMENT>":
        # start a new document
        document = []
        docs.append(document)
    else:
        # append to the current one
        document.append(line)

# convert lists of lines into a string
docs = ['\n'.join(document) for document in docs]
```

Comment: That joins all the lines together, I am attempted to get them the documents to be individual, such as looking up doc1 gives me look on the bright side of life, 2 gives me look on the very brightside of the moon, I just want to disregard the <new document> when I print, and ability to call 1 and be able to read the document

Comment: @Ryan: pretty sure that's what mine does (untested...) with `docs[0]` etc

Comment: how would that be reworked to search for different items within the document, such as if i want to know which document contains "moon"

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it for you:

```
docs = file2.read().split("<NEW DOCUMENT>\n")
```

It gives you a list, not a dictionary, because why would you want a dictionary whose keys are sequential numbers? But if you must have a dictionary, use:

```
new_dict = dict(enumerate(docs))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
In [7]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
    data=f.read()
    dic=dict((i,x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(data.split("<NEW DOCUMENT>")[1:]))
    print dic
   ....:     
   ....:     
{0: 'Look on the bright \nside of Life.', 1: 'look on the very, dark\nside of the Moon'}
```

Comment: Just a general comment about all your answers - why do I need to see the `In [7]:` or `...:`?

Comment: @Eric These comes because I use `IPython` shell.

Comment: That explains why they're not `>>>`, but that wasn't my question. Are you keeping score? - _"Look, I did this and it took me 7 tries"_